# What is this Epic Badge? Legendary Badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, daily-reputation-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

What does this mean?

> Earned at least 200 reputation on 50 days.
>
> Earned at least 200 reputation on 150 days.

Does it mean you have to get 200 reputation on these particular days (50th or 150th day)?

Answer (score 7):

No, it means you have to reach that reputation (200), on 50 or 150 different days respectively.

Comment: Not reach, but actually have strictly more than 200: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57232/is-150-rep-cap-exceeded-alone-enough-for-legendary-badge